# How to connect an industrial sensor to Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I want to use a sensor to read pressure in rooms. But sensor like MPX series isn't capable to read air pressure change under 100 Pa. So I want to use industrial sensor like Dwyer 607 Series, and dont have a clue how to connect it to arduino. Anyone can help?
Thanks :)
Fyi, this is the manual instruction for the sensor http://www.dwyer-inst.com/PDF_files/E_76_low.pdf

Comment: here is a tutorial which explains how you can connect 4-20mA industrial sensors with Arduino.
[How to interface 4-20mA with arduino](https://ncd.io/reading-4-20ma-current-loop-sensors-using-arduino/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That uses the industry standard 4-20mA current loop system. For that you really need a special chip to interface it.

You can [buy shields](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/4-20ma-sensor-board-shield-tutorial-for-arduino-raspberry-pi-intel-galileo/) that interface to 4-20mA current loops.